# Probability equation using arc4random ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random

I want to perform a random action on a button click using probability.
For example: If I click a button there is 6% chance of running A method and 94%chance of running B method

Comment: You may want to show us what you had tried so far and why that was not working the way you hoped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (void)click
{
   int chance = arc4random_uniform(100);

   if (chance < 6)
      [self runA];
   else
      [self runB];
}
```

Comment: What if I have to make it 0.6% chance of A and rest of B?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(arc4random()%100 < 6){
   //RunA
}
else{
  //RunB
}
```

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(100)` is recommended over `arc4random()%100`.

Comment: @MartinR can you give me a link for to explain this？ Thank you very much for pointing out.

Comment: Sure: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html.